# Bibtex true unsort

Tags: bibtex, sorting

My first steps with `bibtex`, with `pdflatex` on a linux machine.

I use `\nocite{*}` so that all references are printed, either cited or not.

All the bibliography style that I have found are sorting the references, either by alphabetic or order of appearance order, "features" that I would like to avoid.

Is there a way to preserve the original order of the `.bib` file ?

(I would like that citing references [1] to [999] does not turn to [1] to [2]).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. BTW: do you know the style `unsrt`? Which document class so you use?

Comment: Does `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` helps?

Comment: unsrt does sort (in order of appearance), precisely the feature I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I'm using \documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\usepackage{epstopdf,SIunits}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.mps,.png,.jpg,.gif}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

Comment: Almost by definition your `.bib` file doesn't have an order: it's just a database with unique keys. My `.bib` file is 'ordered' by date of when I added the entry to the file (most recent at the top). I didn't order it that way by design, but that's what my reference manager does. So you have to choose some ordering method when you list your references. What 'order' do you think your `.bib` file is in?  Maybe we can help you reproduce that order using `bibtex` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see only one reason why you may want to to this: having a `.bib` file specially tailored for a CV or something similar. It's probably better to use `unsrt` in a cleverer way, with `\nocite{<key>}` commands in the preferred order at the start of your document.

However, if you put `\nocite{*}` first, the ordering with the bib style `unsrt` will be the one in the `.bib` file.

Demonstration.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{1,
 author={One Cuthor},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={2012},
}
@article{2,
 author={Two Buthor},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={2012},
}
@article{3,
 author={Three Author},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={2012},
}
@article{4,
 author={Four Zuthor},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={2012},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

A citation~\cite{3}

A citation~\cite{1}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah ! I moved \nocite{*} FIRST and it works !